# Open Command Window here in Explorer

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer, windows-xp

How to add an icon to Windows Explorer toolbar (in Windows XP), that once clicked, opens a command window in selected directory?

In other words, I am looking for MS Powertoys"Open Command Window here" like tool but instead of context menu, for Explorer toolbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [StExBar](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/StExBar.html)

> The StExBar provides many useful
>   commands for your everyday use of
>   Windows explorer. And you can add as
>   many custom commands on your own as
>   you like.
>
> [image]
>
> The
>   commands are not just available from
>   the toolbar, but also via hotkeys and
>   via a context menu!
>
> **Have you ever needed to open a console window while you were using
>   the explorer?** And to have that
>   console already set to the directory
>   you're showing in explorer right now?
>   Well, StExBar provides that with one
>   simple mouseclick. There's also a
>   hotkey defined for this: simply press
>   Ctrl-M to open the console. A
>   'lightweight' console is also
>   available. Simply enter the command
>   you like to execute into the edit box
>   on the right of the StExBar and hit
>   enter. The command will be executed in
>   the system console.

Comment: I registered on this site, and answered enough questions to get enough rep, just so I could say thank you this answer. It's lightweight, customisable and solves 2 things that have been annoying me for years.

Answer (score 0):

Without external tools, you can just merge a .reg file to the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\OpenCmdHere]
@="Open command window here"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\OpenCmdHere\command]
@="cmd.exe /k pushd %L"
```

I couldn't find a way to add it to Desktop Context menu in Windows XP, in later versions (Vista+) you can use `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\` to add this to Desktop context menu.